# Fiddler doesn't allow apps to establish a connecton on Android

Tags: android, proxy, fiddler

I'm using Fiddler /w Android 9 through a proxy.
Tried on multiple versions, 4.0 , Fiddler Everywhere 0.0.5 and Fiddle Insider 0.10  + Win/Linux/Mac.

The issue is the same.

Chrome Requests get sniffed easily. HTTPS requests made by chrome pass through and work just fine.

But mobile apps (like Youtube even) just do a few CONNECT attempts, get a 200 response but it just keeps making more CONNECT requests. 
Example response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 02:20:42.777
Connection: close
```

I've went through every google result for a number of queries regarding this.

Everything's configured properly on both the PC + Phone. But still it isn't working.

Comment: How did you install the Fiddler root certificate? Since Android 6 you need a rooted device and install the certificate as system certificate. Otherwise it will be ignored by the apps by default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intercepting app https traffic on Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61159958/intercepting-app-https-traffic-on-android-device)

Comment: Check also: https://feedback.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere/1469834-fiddler-everywhere-v0-10-0-not-working-with-android-emulator

Comment: But I do suffer from the same issue..