# Emulator won't connect to internet over proxy connection

Tags: security, proxy, android-emulator, burp

Using burp suit to intercept traffic of android emulator. When I connect the emulator to the same proxy as the burp suite the emulator internet connection get lost. The proxy IP I'm using is my router IP address.

Using burp suit to intercept traffic of android emulator. When I connect the emulator to the same proxy as the burp suite the emulator internet connection get lost. The proxy IP I'm using is my router IP address.

I have turned off firewall settings and real time protection. I connect the emulator to localhost IP 10.0.2.2 but that also failed to connect to internet. Changed the proxy settings from emulator settings and from the android settings. nothing worked so far. I'm new to this security testing.

Comment: Where do you configure the proxy in your emulator, in the emulator settings or the emulator itself? 10.0.2.2 only works if you are in the emulator itself not in it's emulator configuration. Is your emulator rooted and have you installed the Burp root CA certificate as system certificate? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61169464/150978