Unable to Connect Android Phone to Charles Proxy - SSL Handshake Failure
Body:
I am trying to connect my Android phone to Charles Proxy to inspect network traffic. However, I'm encountering issues with the connection. Here are the details:
Steps I've Taken:
Installed Charles Proxy on my computer:
Charles Proxy Version: [insert version number]
Operating System: [Windows/macOS/Linux]
Configured Charles Proxy for SSL Proxying:
Opened Charles.
Went to Proxy > SSL Proxying Settings.
Enabled SSL Proxying and added * to the list of locations to be proxied.
Configured Proxy Settings on the Android Device:
Connected my Android phone to the same Wi-Fi network as my computer.
Went to Settings > Network & internet > Wi-Fi.
Long pressed on the connected Wi-Fi network and selected Modify network.
Checked Show advanced options.
Set Proxy to Manual.
Entered my computer’s IP address in the Proxy hostname field.
Entered 8888 in the Proxy port field.
Saved the settings.
Installed the Charles Root Certificate on the Android Device:
Opened a web browser on my Android device and navigated to http://charlesproxy.com/getssl.
Downloaded the Charles root certificate.
Went to Settings > Security > Encryption & credentials > Install from storage.
Located and selected the downloaded certificate file to install it.
Named the certificate.
Verified that the certificate is listed under the User tab in Trusted credentials.


refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/3879847

if first one not working try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25992879/3879847

Its working before but not now without these solutions. And these solutions is not working as well.

pls share the error logs

Apps by default ignore user certificates. You need to configure the app to trust user certificates or directly include the proxy Ca certificate in the app as trusted root: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61169464/150978
