Can't see android app http traffic with fiddler
Hi I'm trying to capture the traffic of a legacy Cordova app with fiddler classic but with a device with Android 11 I can't see the app traffic, other apps a working fine...
The same app on a device with Android 7 works fine with fiddler...
Any help?
Thanks

You did not write that the device is rooted and how you installed the Fiddler root Ca certificate, therefore I assume you just installed it as user cert, which makes it useless for 99% of all apps. Please read my answer here on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61169464/150978

Both the devices are not rooted e it's simple http traffic, I simple set the device network to use fiddler as proxy

What does the app do with and without proxy? Some apps use a custom HTTP client which ignores proxy settings, in such a case I would use mitmproxy in Wireguard mode. This way it doesn't matter if the app uses or ignores Android proxy settings as all traffic is redirected via Wireguard VPN to mitmproxy.

It just send request to an api server, with other devices it works fine with fiddler, it's just with a zebra TC21 that doesn't work... With others zebra devices (with lower Android versions) works fine either with and without fiddler
