android apps connection error when using burpsuite for traffic interception
I'm trying to pentest an android app using Burpsuite, so:
1- I set the proxy and port in Burpsuite as 192.168.1.249:8080 (my PC IP), and I set the proxy in my android device WIFI as 192.168.1.249 and PORT as 8080.
2- I headed to https://burp and downloaded the cacert.der certificate and installed it from my device settings, (for VPN and apps).
3- I also generated a .der certificate and installed it on my phone.
-THE PROBLEM
THE APP I WANT TO PENTEST HAS NO CONNECTION beside other apps.
-Notes
my android version is 9 (not rooted)
intercept off on burpsuite.
some apps work like internet browser (Brave Browser) and instagram app.

Installing the proxy certificate on Android has no effect on most apps. Only apps that explicitly allow user installed root CA certificates (like Chrome) accept the proxy certificate. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/61159958/150978 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/62730978/150978 (different proxy, same problem).
