HTTPS request using ksoap2 Kotlin
I'm developing an application that uses a SOAP API, and I'm using the ksoap2 library within Kotlin. I need to make an HTTPS request. I have a .pfx certificate with a specific password, and I also have a username/password that serve as credentials. In WcfStorm, the request works fine after downloading the certificate and configuring the username/password authentication at the security level with the TLS protocol in the configuration values. Now I've tried to implement this in code, but I’m stuck and don't know how to proceed. Has anyone encountered a similar problem, and how did you resolve it? Please provide a detailed explanation, as I’m a junior developer. Below is my current code.
Example function from the SoapClient.kt:
fun getSomething(context: Context): List<String> {
    val namespace = "NAMESPACE"
    val methodName = "GetSomething"
    val soapAction = "$namespace/FIXEDVALUE/$methodName"
    val urlString = getServiceUrl(context)

    val request = SoapObject(namespace, methodName)

    val username = "USERNAME"
    val password = "PASSWORD"

    request.addProperty("username", USERNAME)
    request.addProperty("password", PASSWORD)

    val envelope = SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11).apply {
        dotNet = true
        setOutputSoapObject(request)
    }

    val headerList = listOf(
        HeaderProperty("soapAction", soapAction)
    )

    try {
        val url = URL(urlString)

        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12").apply {
            load(context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.CERTIFIKAT), "SIFRA".toCharArray())
        }

        val keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()).apply {
            init(keyStore, "SIFRA".toCharArray())
        }

        val trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()).apply {
            init(keyStore)
        }

        val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS").apply {
            init(keyManagerFactory.keyManagers, trustManagerFactory.trustManagers, null)
        }

        val transport = CustomHttpsTransportSE(url.host, url.port, url.file, 60000, sslContext.socketFactory)
        transport.debug = true

        transport.call(soapAction, envelope, headerList)

        val response = envelope.response as SoapObject

        return response

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return emptyList()
    }
}

CustomHttpsTransportSE.kt:
class CustomHttpsTransportSE(
    host: String,
    port: Int,
    file: String,
    timeout: Int,
    private val sslSocketFactory: SSLSocketFactory
) : HttpsTransportSE(host, port, file, timeout) {

}


I receive 500 http status in line: transport.call(soapAction,envelope,headerList)
I've tried numerous things, but I haven't found an exact solution to this problem anywhere, nor complete code that could help me.

Have you tried what happens if you provide a wrong password? There are two versions of pkcs#12 files (one using DES and one using AES) and I am not sure what Android version is required to read the new AES version. The problem is that Java usually don't throw an error if it can not read such a file but simply actly like the password is wrong and if the library simply ignores such errors...

@Robert When I provide wrong password, I receive exception: java.io.IOException: PKCS12 key store mac invalid - wrong password or corrupted file. I think that the problem is somewhere in code.

Then an HTTP 500 can mean everything. In my opinion the best way to debug a HTTP request/response problem is looking at the actual request/response and check if it is as you expect it to be. Therefore I recommend to you using a web proxy like Fiddler, Mitmproxy, Zap add their root CA cert to your app and redirect the traffic through the proxy. Then you will see request and response. See also my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61169464/150978

@Robert Do you think that the code is ok? I was looking for some similar example, but I didn't find it. Do you know any example in Kotlin with https request and username/password authentication?

I don't think that the TLS authentication is the problem. May be your SOAP request is wrong or not the way the server expect it to be.
